# Is my solution to this ordinary differential equation correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the general solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}= \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{1-r}$, where $x>0$ and $r$ is a positive constant.

Here is what I did:
$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{yx^{\space r}}{xy^{\space r}}\\&=\frac{1}{y^{\space r-1}}\cdot\frac{x^{\space r-1}}{1}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}&\implies y^{\space r-1}dy=x^{\space r-1}dx\\&\implies \frac{y^{\space r}}{r} = \frac{x^{\space r}}{r} +C\end{align}$$
where C is the constant of integration.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, you can also solve for $y(x)$.

Comment: Thats correct. You can write it $y^r=x^r+c$